# How do I say in german "car parking fine lawyer"?

Tags: word-choice

I would like to make a search on Google for finding information about a lawyer company specialized on this.

I know only the word `Strafzettel`.

I've found many words but which is the more correct for saying: `"lawyer for defending against car fines"`? I'm reporting the list of words just to clarify my difficulty. Ignore it for the answer!

Berufung, Gesuch, Regress, umsortieren, appellieren?
ausgezeichnet, fein, Geldstrafe, gelinde, Strafe, Strafzettel, zart?
Advokat, Anwalt, Rechtsanwalt, Rechtsberater, Strafverteidiger, Generalanwalt, Rechtsbeistand?

Comment: I assume you've got the words you listed from a dictionary? You could optimize your search by using a dictionary which put the words into groups, i.e. categorize them. Then you would know, that "fein" is the translation for the adjective "fine", meaning *very good*, and not the noun as used in your context.

Comment: @Em1: Translating "fine" with "fein" is about the quality you would expect from an automated computer translation. It very clearly means "Bußgeld" or "Strafe" in this context.

Comment: @Damon Right. A machine translator can't know that you didn't mean "a car that is parking a fine lawyer", can it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to §1 of the German "[Fachanwaltsordnung](http://www.brak.de/fuer-anwaelte/berufsrecht/)" the following specializations of a lawyer are recognized (in bold the one you are looking for):

> - Verwaltungsrecht
> - Steuerrecht
> - Arbeitsrecht
> - Sozialrecht
> - Familienrecht
> - Strafrecht
> - Insolvenzrecht
> - Versicherungsrecht
> - Medizinrecht
> - Miet- und Wohnungseigentumsrecht
> - **Verkehrsrecht**
> - Bau- und Architektenrecht
> - Erbrecht
> - Transport- und Speditionsrecht
> - gewerblichen Rechtsschutz
> - Handels- und Gesellschaftsrecht
> - Urheber- und Medienrecht
> - Informationstechnologierecht
> - Bank- und Kapitalmarktrecht
> - Agrarrecht

A lawyer specialized in legal issues of traffic including fines hence would be called *"Fachanwalt für Verkehrsrecht"*.

Answer (score 9):

You are looking for a [Fachanwalt für Verkehrsrecht](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fachanwalt_f%C3%BCr_Verkehrsrecht).